# Count obstacles on the roads

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, network-analyst

I have a set of points (about 400) shp file  which represents cities and the shp file of the road network. Also I have a new shp file of obstacles on the road. Now I want to count obstacles on the shortest routes between all of 400 places. Does somebody know how to do this?

Comment: Do you have any idea how the routes between should be built? What if it's possible to drive between all of the cities avoiding meeting obstacles? Please elaborate more on the logic.

Comment: The route between is the shortest route between two places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are on Network Analyst and ArcGIS, you could use Python for this:

1. You need to construct all possible pairs of cities. That is, your shapefile of 400 cities will be your input for [permutations list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of length 2.

So, the `cities = ['city1','city2','city3']` will give you with the help of `list(itertools.permutations(cities,2))`:

```
[('city1', 'city2'),
 ('city1', 'city3'),
 ('city2', 'city1'),
 ('city2', 'city3'),
 ('city3', 'city1'),
 ('city3', 'city2')]
```

The shortest route may be different depending on the direction of travel, but if you want to ignore this, you could use [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) with `list(itertools.combinations(cities,2))` instead which would give you:

```
[('city1', 'city2'),
 ('city1', 'city3'),
 ('city1', 'city4'),
 ('city2', 'city3'),
 ('city2', 'city4'),
 ('city3', 'city4')]
```

2. Now when you have your pairs, you need to build multiple routes connecting the cities. I would usually use OD Cost Matrix solver for this just loading all 400 cities both as origins and destination, but this solver doesn't return the actual shape of the route. So, you have to use the [Route solver](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/route.htm).
3. Load pairs of cities creating individual routes, you will have about 80K routes to build when having the route from the `city1` to the `city2` is sufficient and you ignore the route from the `city2` to the `city1`. If you do need to have routes for traveling in both directions, the number of routes would be twice as more, about 160K routes.
4. Solve the Route layer. You can export the Routes sublayer into an separate shapefile.
5. Use Python or ModelBuilder to iterate over every route counting the number of obstacles (point features) that are located close enough to the root with the Select By Location tool (you'll probably want to apply a slight search tolerance value in case the obstacle point is not located topologically on the street line feature).

Learn more about [Network Analyst](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/what-is-network-analyst-.htm) and [Python in ArcGIS](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/python/what-is-python-.htm).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I need. But, could you please send me some video tutorial of this, because I am still beginner. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The help for Network Analyst is excellent. You might watch some videos on video.esri.com for Network Analyst and Python. Network Analyst help pages also has tutorial: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/What_is_the_Network_Analyst_guide_book/0047000001r8000000/

Comment: I have one more question. Does it mean that I must manually add combination by combination in Route solver if I want to save routes shapefiles? It is a lot of combinations and I want to know is there any way to do it faster?

Comment: import arcpy
import itertools

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\path\to\workspace"

base_shapefile = "some_shapefile.shp"

oid_field = arcpy.Describe(base_shapefile).OIDFieldName
feature_count = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(base_shapefile).getOutput(0))

for (i, j) in itertools.combinations(range(feature_count), 2):
    arcpy.Select_analysis(base_shapefile , "combination_%i_%i.shp" % (i, j), '"%s" in (%i, %i)' % (oid_field, i, j))   I have used this script and I get the point shapefile for each combination.

Comment: You shouldn't create new shapefiles for every pair. What you need to do is to load each pair into the Route layer by using the Add Locations tool. Each pair should get a unique route name; this will give you the Route layer with N thousands unique routes that will be solved in one run. http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//004800000005000000.htm